# MySQL как начать вывод строк после определенного ID?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сайт вопросов и ответов, в нём, в конце списка вопросов, повесил кнопку "Показать еще" (вопросы). Эта кнопка передает ajax запросом в php скрипт, параметр позиции элемента с которого необходимо вернуть новую пачку вопросов. Если использовать в качестве этого параметра, её порядковый номер, например 10, соответственно SQL запрос, в теле php скрипта, будет типа `SELECT .... LIMIT 10, 40` (40 - количество), то появляется проблема, так как если, после того как кнопка будет сформирована и выведена в браузере пользователя, будут добавлены новые вопросы, то скрипт продублирует уже выведенные вопросы, так как позиция таблицы уже сместилась. Пришла идея использовать в качестве стартовой позиции - идентификатор последнего вопроса, что-то вроде `startID`, но не знаю как это реализовать, что-то вроде `SELECT .... LIMIT $startID, 40`, запрос должен вывести 40 записей, после того как встретит запись с заданным `startID`. Решение `WHERE id > $startID LIMIT 40` не годится так, как строки отсортированы не по полю id. Позволяет ли язык SQL реализовать эту идею?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, пагинация через offset предполагает такие артефакты, не говоря о том что такая пагинация медлительна. Направление для решения вы выбрали верное, но вам нужен не абстрактный ID, а сперва вам необходимо явно и недвусмысленно зафиксировать сортировку результата. Запрос `where .. limit` для пагинации не имеет смысла. У вас обязан быть `order by` при том включающий в себя какой-либо признак уникальности. Например, имея уникальный идентификатор id и если вы хотите сортировать по не уникальному полю created_at с датой создания сущности, то вам необходима сортировка:

```
order by created_at desc, id desc
```

Затем, при необходимости загрузить следующий фрагмент данных, вы передаёте на backend оба значение: и created_at и id последней строки которую вы показали пользователю. И запрашиваете следующую порцию данных:

```
 WHERE (created_at, id) < (?, ?)
 ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Просто, элегантно, соответствует стандарту, быстро по составному индексу `(created_at, id)`. Нормально поддерживается только в postgresql... В mysql выполняется логика верно, но без поддержки индекса (впрочем, может у меня устарели сведения), так что объясняем необходимую логику фильтрации вручную:

```
 WHERE created_at <= ?
    AND NOT (created_at = ? AND id >= ?)
 ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC
 limit 10
```

По материалам [статьи](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) Markus Winand, которые весьма рекомендую к прочтению.

Comment: Спасибо большое, до меня дошло.

Comment: Если лучше ничего не предложат, отмечу как решение.